# Facebook deep linking always opens store in android & app store

Tags: android, ios, ruby-on-rails, facebook, react-native

I'm building an mobile app using React Native for both android and iOS and i had to implement Facebook Deep Linking, but it always opens App Store or Play Store based on the device only if `al:web:should_fallback` is set to true, and redirect user to website if set `al:web:should_fallback` to false.

How can i implement the correct scenario which is redirect user to app if it's installed and to store if app isn't installed .

Here's my configuration :

```
<meta property="al:ios:app_store_id" content="xxxxx" />
<meta property="al:ios:app_name" content="xxxxx" />
<meta property="al:ios:url" content="xxxxxx" />
<meta property="al:android:url" content="xxxxxx" />
<meta property="al:android:package" content="com.xxx" />
<meta property="al:android:app_name" content="xxxx" />
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="xxxxx" />
<meta property="og:title" content="xxxx" />
<meta property="og:description" content="xxxx" />
```